# pgfplotstable - Make rows bold and add a backgroup color using values from two columns

Tags: formatting, conditionals, pgfplotstable

I am trying to get some rows in my data to show both as bold and with a background color. More specifically, I want my table to have bold rows where Group = 1 and at the same time I want rows to have a background blue color if Color = 1.In this process i do not want to lose the precision in any of the columns.

I have tried several combinations, but have not been able to solve this problem. A MWE is posted below:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs, ifthen}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep= semicolon]{
A;B;C;Group;Color 
C0;100;0.9;0;1
C1;90;16.0;1;1
C2;80;1.6;2;0
C3;70;1.0;0;1
C4;60;12.0;0;1
C5;50;13.5;1;0
}\mytable

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill, precision=0, set thousands separator={}} 

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep = semicolon,
    columns = {A, B, C, Group, Color },
    columns/A/.style={ string type, column type = {l}},
    columns/B/.style={ column type = {r}},
    columns/C/.style={ column type = {r}, precision = 1},
    columns/Group/.style={ column type = {r}, precision = 1},
    columns/Color/.style={ column type = {r}, precision = 1},
    %
    every column/.style={
        postproc cell content/.append code={
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Group}\of{\mytable}
            \ifthenelse{ \pgfplotsretval = 1 }
                {\pgfkeysalso{/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$\bf}{$}}}
            %
            % Want to add red color to the rows where Color = 1, and keep the rows bold where Group = 1. 
            %
            % Commented out: My attempt that did not work!
            %
            % \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Color}\of{\mytable}
            % \ifthenelse{ \pgfplotsretval = 1 }
            %    {\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\relax\cellcolor{red}##1}} 
            %
        }
    }
    ]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

- BTW: I think, amazingly, there is no command `every column/.style={...}`
  `€dit: ...in older versions of pgfplotstable. But, it does not matter, because we do not need this command in the following.`
- It seems, due to your different column styles, you have to repeat your if-condition for each relevant column; while respecting (and adding) the specific style for the current column.

Your desired common styles are

```
\pgfplotstableset{
CellColor/.style={postproc cell content/.append code={
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Color}\of{\mytable}%
\ifthenelse{\pgfplotsretval = 1 }% if 
{\pgfkeysalso{/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{red}}{}}}% then
{}% else
}},
CellBold/.style={postproc cell content/.append code={
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Group}\of{\mytable}%
\ifthenelse{\pgfplotsretval = 1 }% if 
{\pgfkeysalso{/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$\bf}{$} }}% then
{}% else
}},
}
```

So you have to say: 
`columns/A/.style={ string type, column type = {l},% specific column A
CellColor, CellBold % common
}` 
analog for column B, but 
`columns/C/.style={column type=r, precision = 1,% specific column C
CellColor, CellBold % common
}`

**Alltogether:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs, ifthen}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep= semicolon]{
A;B;C;Group;Color 
C0;100;0.9;0;1
C1;90;16.0;1;1
C2;80;1.6;2;0
C3;70;1.0;0;1
C4;60;12.0;0;1
C5;50;13.5;1;0
}\mytable

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill, precision=0, set thousands separator={}} 

\pgfplotstableset{
CellColor/.style={postproc cell content/.append code={
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Color}\of{\mytable}%
\ifthenelse{\pgfplotsretval = 1 }% if 
{\pgfkeysalso{/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{red}}{}}}% then
{}% else
}},
CellBold/.style={postproc cell content/.append code={
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Group}\of{\mytable}%
\ifthenelse{\pgfplotsretval = 1 }% if 
{\pgfkeysalso{/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$\bf}{$} }}% then
{}% else
}},
}


\pgfplotstabletypeset[, 
    col sep = semicolon,
    columns = {A, B, C, Group, Color },
%    columns/A/.style={ string type, column type = {l}},
%    columns/B/.style={ column type = {r}},
%    columns/C/.style={ column type = {r}, precision = 1},
    columns/Group/.style={ column type = {r}, precision = 1},
    columns/Color/.style={ column type = {r}, precision = 1},
%
%every column/.style={} % 
%
columns/A/.style={ string type, column type = {l},% specific column A
CellColor, CellBold % common
},
columns/B/.style={column type=r,% specific column B
CellColor, CellBold % common
},
columns/C/.style={column type=r, precision = 1,% specific column C
CellColor, CellBold % common
},
]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```